# Button align is not overriding in layout.xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I created a button:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Button
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/barBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="32dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@drawable/sel_btn_bar"
/>
```

It's ok, then I'm trying to place it in other layout

```xml
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:src="@drawable/bar"
            />

    <include layout="@layout/btn_bar"
             android:layout_alignParentRight="false"
             android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
    <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="@string/city_fragment_title"
            />
</RelativeLayout>
```

However that button is only aligned left when I'm removing `android:layout_alignParentRight` in button declaration. Why?

### Update

It seems that align does not work when including a layout.

Answer (score 0):

when you defined the button you already used

```
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

which will be applied to the button try to define alignments when including the button. but I think you should define the button inside the layout instead of including it.